# Laravel nested information

Tags: laravel-4

I am using larval and calling a view from a url like this:

```
a href="{{ URL::to('questions/MC', '155', false); }}" class="save" id="mc"><span        class="questionTypes"
```

The 155 needs to be dynamic like this:

```
{{ $chapter }}
```

I tried this:

```
a href="{{ URL::to('questions/MC', '{{ $chapter }}', false); }}" class="save" id="mc"><span class="questionTypes"
```

This did not work can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('questions/MC', $chapter, false); }}" class="save" id="mc">
```

When you encounter problems simliar to this, try think of `{{` as `<?php echo`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this too, using `Laravel`'s `HTML::link()`

```
{{ Html::link("questions/MC/$chapter", "ChapterOne", array("class" => "save", "id" => "mc")) }}
```

Comment: I like this approach too